# Multer saves file with 0kb

Tags: node.js, multer

I'm using multer to save files in a nodejs route, when i make the upload the file is saved without extension and with 0kb, but even with this I can access him with the url from the browser, like http://localhost:3333/filepath/43a3d361-0d36-4760-ad81-380c8e2399b7:filename.pdf

But if I go directly in the file path and try to open, it doesn't work.
Is there any place the file is actually saved besides the one I put in the destination?

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
 const fileName = `${file.originalname}`;
 cb(null, fileName);
},
destination: (req, file, cb) => {
const destination = path.join(
  __dirname,
  "..",
  "..",
  "..",
  "static",
  "private",
  "contratos"
);
  console.log(destination);
  cb(null, destination);
  },
});

const upload = multer({
storage,
 limits: {
   fileSize: 20000000,
 },
});
```